# Laravel File::get() File does not exist at path Exception

Tags: php, laravel, file-get-contents

I am trying to get an external file using the Laravel File System but i keep getting a `File does not exist at path` Exception

here is my code

```
File::get('http://lorempixel.com/272/172');
```

The Laravel function being called

```
 public function get($path, $lock = false)
{
    if ($this->isFile($path)) {
        return $lock ? $this->sharedGet($path) : file_get_contents($path);
    }

    throw new FileNotFoundException("File does not exist at path {$path}");
}
```

i have tested `file_get_contents('http://lorempixel.com/272/172')` on my server and that works fine.

this is very strange if do `dd($path)` within the if statement i get

`"/home/vagrant/Code/test/storage/framework/sessions/fdb554540ba30a38464950b36908fa20e0ee94cc"` returned

If i do `dd($path)` outside the if statement i get `http://lorempixel.com/272/172` returned

i'm baffled

Answer (score 4):

`File::get` is only for local files, in a laravel version prior to 4.1 you can use `File::getRemote`:

```
$content = File::getRemote("http://lorempixel.com/272/172");
```

But it is removed in laravel 4.1. According to @taylorotwell, the creator of laravel, it was insecure. All it did was call `file_get_contents` so just replace it with `file_get_contents` and you should be good.

Comment: File::getRemote has been deprecated in 5.1